# urllib doesn't work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to use urllib for the simple request as in below:

```
      import urllib
      my_url = "https://realpython.com/practice/aphrodite.html"
      my_open = urllib.request.urlopen(my_url)
      my_op = my_open.read().decode('utf-8')
      print(my_op)
```

When I run code it returns me request from my database, which is not related to the urllib. Moreover, I got an error as in below:

```
  import urllib.request
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 52, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, selectors
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 290, in <module>
    class SelectSelector(_BaseSelectorImpl):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 317, in SelectSelector
    _select = select.select
AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'select'
```

I can uninstall and install any library except urllib. Please guide me about this error.

Comment: Possibly you have a file called `select.py` laying around somewhere that is shadowing the built-in `select` module.  `import select; print(select.__file__)` will tell you where it is.

Comment: I checked that too. I have no any file like select.py

Comment: please paste the **full** traceback. What we have here is not **the full** traceback.

Comment: How did you install that Python 3? (Is there any reason you're using the system Python 3, and not a `brew`-installed one?)

Comment: solved guys. created free select.py without any code now it works thank you so much all.

Comment: @jasonharper please write your answer separately.  I would like to accept that as an answer because it gave me an idea. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a separate file with the name of select.py and didn't include any code to that. After that, I didn't get any error.